# Configurando API Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

Depois que você cria uma conta no Google Analytics, o Google te manda um código, esse código deve ser inserido na página index do site ou em todas as páginas relacionadas ao site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caio, boa noite.

Esse snippet deve ser inserido em todas as páginas do seu site que você deseja mensurar. É recomendado que você insira dentro do **head** do site.

Eu sempre recomendo que utilize o Google Tag Manager(ou qualquer outro tag manager) para implementar as tags e fazer qualquer tipo de tagging, pois além de tornar o processo e manutenção mais simples, torna o carregamento assíncrono.